# How to add a page into ribbon form at runtime?

Tags: c#, devexpress

i have a ribbon form ,a configuration form and buttons as modify,add,save and delete.I want to reflect configuration form into ribbon form. I have added configuration form as a page into ribbon form at design page but i am unable to see at runtime.please help me in it using `c#` code.I am using VS2005 C#.thank you in advance

Comment: please reply as early as possible.

Comment: Provide us with your code. What code does the designer have? Do you have any code in code behind that works with your page?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late post.I was trying to change the riboon page for Devexpress Ribbon Form.
This can be achieved by using even RibbonSelectedPage_Changed and RibbonSelectedPage_Changing event.

Answer (score -1):

tip:

when you use components in one "form" you can use "show form in text view" and know as create your form and your components very easy

try it

VIEW FORM TEXT

Comment: This is a C# question

Comment: Sorry sir but I have not asked the question clearly but now i m cleared.  I was confused about how to reflect another form into the ribbon form.For eg. I  have one ribbon form for configuration and other forms are as parameter configuration and device configuration.On click of parameter it should display only parameter info.I have taken parameter and device as ribbon page.Now my question is that how to reflect parameter configuration form on click of ribbon page parameter?